# Codename One - Button to close an app

Tags: codenameone

I tried to create a Button to close (exit) the app, but it doesn't work, because, after clicking the button, the app is not closed (it's put in the background) and the native Android browser is opened (???).

```
Button button = new Button("Close the app");
button.addActionListener(l -> {System.exit(0);});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Display.getInstance().exitApplication()`.

Notice mobile apps don't provide exit buttons only logout buttons. If you provide an exit button in your app you might be rejected by the app review process in itunes.

Comment: So usually is the operating system the only one that can terminate an app?

Comment: Yes. In iOS and Android you have the builtin home button (Android also has a back button) both of which provide that functionality in the OS. Adding a regular exit button is generally considered bad form unless you provide added value such as logout. Normally apps aren't exited. You just stop background processes and the OS will suspend the app. That's good because the app will launch faster (warm start) then next time around but won't consume noticeable battery life. In fact exiting and relaunching frequently might take up more battery life overall.

Comment: I did an app last year and had an built in close app button (made in Unity) which was uploaded to the appstore/ Itunes.